# How to target the second item in an array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm playing with the jquery.ui autocomplete script.

Please refer to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alforno/d3t7V/)

So, instead of

```
colors = [['White', '#fff'], ['Black', '#000'], ['Red', '#f00'], ['Green', '#0f0'], ['Blue', '#00f']];
```

I'm getting data in the same array form but from a PHP script after querying database.
so in my script, `colors = data;`

Question is I need to alter the second item in the array's display, just need to add brackets around the value. How do I do that, please?

Here's my script

```
$("document").ready(function(){       
      var data = {
        "action": "test"
      };
      data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
      $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "store2.php?target="+target, //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
          //console.log(data);

       var useThis=[];
          if(target=="subject")
          {
              useThis = [{
              name: 'level',
              minWidth: 'auto',
              symbol: ''},
              {
              name: 'subject',
              minWidth: 'auto',
              symbol: '&nbsp;>&nbsp; '},
               {
              name: 'posts',
              minWidth: 'auto',
              symbol: ' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; '},
              ];

          }
          else  if(target=="location")
          {
              useThis = [{
              name: 'level',
              minWidth: 'auto',
              symbol: ''}];

          }
          else
          {
              useThis = [{
              name: 'level',
              minWidth: 'auto',
              symbol: ''}];

          }
          var columns = useThis;
          colors = data;


          //alert(selectThis);
          var valueV=targetItem.attr("value");
          targetItem.mcautocomplete({
          showHeader: true,
          columns: columns,
          source: colors,
          select: function(event, ui) 
          {
              // Set the input box's value
              var selectThis = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0];//get only the first class
              if(target=="subject")
              {
              this.value = (ui.item ? ui.item[0] +" > " + ui.item[selectThis] : '');
              }
              else
              {
                   this.value = (ui.item ? ui.item[selectThis] : '');
              }


              // Set the output div's value
             // $('#show_subject') && $('#show_place').text(ui.item ? (target+ ' = ' + ui.item[selectThis] + ui.item[2]) : 'Select a subject');
              if(target=="subject")
              {
              $('input[name="try"]').val(ui.item[3]);
              }
               if(target=="location")
              {

              $('input[name="lat"]').val(ui.item[1]);
              $('input[name="lon"]').val(ui.item[2]);

              }
             if(target=="tutor")
              {

              $('input[name="tutor"]').val(ui.item[0]);
              }
              return false;
          }
          });
         }
});
```

PHP

```
$statement1="SELECT * FROM categories,subjects WHERE categories.catid=subjects.catid";

$target=$_GET["target"];
```

//the "catname", "subname","subcount" and "catid" are columns names in the database. So I cannot add brackets here otherwise I won't get their values right.

```
$sql=$statement1;
        $v_1="catname";
        $v_2="subname";
        $v_3="subcount";
        $v_4="catid";

    $stmt =connection::$pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();

            $json=array();
            while($row = $stmt->fetch())
            {

              array_push($json,array($row[$v_1],$row[$v_2],$row[$v_3],$row[$v_4]));

            }

    echo json_encode($json)
```

SO how do I target a specific item and add brackets around it?

Comment: Please check updated http://jsfiddle.net/d3t7V/250/   . I have added their column `Index` name. You can do like that.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi, I'm aware of it and thats how I added my third forths values into the array. But how to add brackets around the second item when its not a string value but integer?

Comment: Please check http://jsfiddle.net/d3t7V/252/

Comment: Use array like `[['White', '#fff','(0)'], ['Black', '#000','(1)'], ['Red', '#f00','(3)'], ['Green', '#0f0','(4)'], ['Blue', '#00f','(5)']];`

Comment: Add another column in sql and make that `subcountString` and add brackets to that.

Comment: use like `array_push($json,array($row[$v_1],$row[$v_2],"("+$row[$v_3]+")",$row[$v_4]));`  check `$row[$v_3]`

Answer (score 0):

I added the brackets on the second item in the array :

```
source: jQuery.each(colors , function(index, value){
                 console.log(value[1]);
                 value[2] = "("+value[1]+")"; 
               }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `each` loop in `_renderItem` function like following. Hope this will help you.

```
$.each(this.options.columns, function(index, column) {
    var i = column.valueField ? column.valueField : index;

    var itm=item[i];      
    if (i==1) 
        itm='('+item[i]+')';   

    t += '<span style="float:left;min-width:' + column.minWidth + ';">' + itm+'</span>'
});
```

#### [UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d3t7V/254/)